# DB design: For a website with 100 million users

Tags: database-design, performance

I am looking for a suggestion for a DB design not in terms of schema design but how should DB tables be distributed or spread over different servers.

Simply putting: I have 10-15 tables for example which contain all the information of users who register.

But if the number of users is huge (100 million+), should the DB schema be divided into different servers having db instances dedicated to store the data for different tables

What I understand is there should be an optimal limit for the size of data that should be monitored by one DB instance. What if that optimal limit is crossed?

Please advise.

Regards,
Mayank

**Edit:**

Well, I would restate my question and will try to make the things clear.
The things that came in my mind:

1. Write a DBSchema to support the app. The app will allow user registration, status updates etc as in facebook or something
2. Only one DB instance will be used, which can theoritically (may be practically too by postgresql: http://www.postgresql.org/about/) be supported.
3. With the increase of users just increase your server capacity. (Both harddisk and CPUs)

But, as far as I understand, more the data is more time for look up.

Moreover, all data at a central DB may not have flexibilty to spread it throughout the locations with users density.

The different servers may not be placed regionally. So, a thought of things distributed.

Regarding distributed DBs or filesystems I'm not comfortable as much as I'm with SQL DBs.

So, I thought of logically distributing the tables to be monitored under different DB instances/Servers.

I'm trying to write such an app for the first time (Never worked on DBs before :(). Please comment if what I think is weird, or my understanding of DB things are zero or anythings like that.

I'll be highly grateful.

Regards,
Mayank

Comment: @marc_s: The OP is talking about 100 million *users*, not 100 million rows.

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks for the kind response. Well, the obvious question that comes in my mind why did facebook had 1800 running instances of MySql. (Well I understand that they now have moved to NoSql stuff)

Comment: @marc_s: I'm not looking at the number of rows; I'm looking at the number of users. Say only 1% are active at any one time. It looks like the real problem might be how to handle a million concurrent users. I can handle 100 million rows times 15 tables on my desktop computer, but it won't tolerate a million concurrent users.

Comment: @marc_s: Well, 100 million users that got their data stored in DB. Lets suppose server is capable of supporting 1 million concurrent users. But the user info based on some inputs that will be searched for 100,000 users out of 100 million users' data, how efficient will it be?

Comment: as I said - I believe any serious RDBMS can **easily** handle this kind of load

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that if you are even contemplating a database of this size that the first thing you need to do is hire an expert in large database design and high performance. This is a  complex subject that cannot be answered on a forum. It requires that you have full-time expertise available. That is the best way to guarantee a successful implementation.

Answer (score 1):

For a database of huge(read it as colossal) magnitude you would probably want to consider distributed database over a distributed filesystem  like Google's [BigTable](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html)

[HBase](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase) is one such implementation by Apache Hadoop Project which is on [HDFS](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/)

Facebook uses HDFS cluster as well, infact it's the [largest](http://hadoopblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/facebook-has-worlds-largest-hadoop.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But Instead of using distributed database I would consider using normal DBs and distribute the tables under different DB instances. It may give me more control over how the data is distributed. Well, I don't know much about distributed DBs, apologies in case I'm wrong

Comment: @Mayank: If you distribute tables, joins will have to be done between servers. That means data will have to pass between servers. Don't distribute tables; distribute databases. Since you don't know much about distributed databases, you'd better start learning today.

Comment: @Catcall: I think internally distributed DBs must be doing the same things (but more optimally). I mean If I do a TABLE join its quite possible the actual stored data is at 2 different servers. Can carefully partitioned table be advised in place of distributed database. `The reason for my reluctance to distributed database is I've read at many places that they are not as reliable as Oracle/PostgreSql when comes to concurrency`

Comment: @Mayank: Do you think you can do a better job at managing your imaginary concurrency problems than the programmers at Oracle? If you have a lot of concurrent users, you probably need to think about load-balancing servers, replication, and things like that. You need to fill in the gaps in your knowledge. Right now, you seem to have a solution--storing tables on different servers--in search of a problem.